# Landscape iPad shows view in Portrait and then quickly rotates it to Landscape

Tags: ipad, screen-rotation

I have a little issue with an application I'm building for the iPad.  I have several views that are fixed in portrait mode, and others that can work in either portrait or landscape mode.  Everything is fine - I have shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: giving me the correct results, and views do eventually end up in the right orientation.

I say "eventually" because a couple of my views have this odd behavior when I have the device in landscape mode where when I switch to them they come up in Portrait mode and visible rotate to Landscape mode.  It's pretty fast, but it's visible and irritating.  The odd thing is that it only happens in two of the 3 views - the third view doesn't have that behavior.  It's consistent - every time I go to the "problem" views they give me the same annoying behavior.

Has anybody else seen this?  What am I doing wrong that is causing this?

Comment: How are you adding the view controllers to your view heirarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all supported orientations in your Info.plist

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```